# Training Multinomial Classifier using chi2 selected features for TFIDF weight matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am loading my pre-classified documents that will be used for classifier training. I vecorizing them, then calculated the weight using tfidf, and used chi2 selelction features method. But an error appears durinig multinomialNB training. The code is

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
train_files=load_files('c:\\python34\\nltk_data\\corpora\\crimettest           train',shuffle=True)
#vector data to frequncy vales
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_files.data)
#vector data to TF vales
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
X_new = chi2(X_train_tfidf,train_files.target)
#train classifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_new,train_files.target)
```

then i modified my code with changing last line as :

```
X= SelectKBest(chi2,k=20)
X_new=X.fit_transform(X_train_tfidf,train_files.target)
#train classifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_new,train_files.target)
#predict new documents
path='c:\\python34\\nltk_data\\corpora\\crime\\class'
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader (path,'.*\.txt')
docs_new=[]
files=corpus.fileids()
for i in files :
f=(open(path+'\\'+i , 'r')).read()
docs_new.append(f)
X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)
predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)
for doc,category in  zip(files, predicted):
print('predicted',doc,train_files.target_names[category])
```

[the following error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu9D5.png)

can any body help me ?

Comment: The method `chi2()` doesnt return your new training data X, as you have used it here. It returns statistics for each feature. See [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html) and [example on how to use it for feature reduction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_compare_reduction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-compare-reduction-py)

Comment: Also you need to provide the exact error and its full stack trace for us to be able to help you.